# How to resolve my jquery conflict?

Tags: javascript, jquery, conflict

I'm having trouble with a my website. Seems like once I incorporated a testimonials slider, my image slider becomes dead. I'm sure it has to do with 2 different JavaScripts but I don't know anything about JavaScript and can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be amazing.

```
<!-- Javascript -->
<script src="js/ddsmoothmenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/contentslider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jcarousellite_1.0.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/DIN_500.font.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/menu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tabs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<!-- Testimonials -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.quovolver.js"></script>

    <!-- Testimonials Test Zone -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('blockquote').quovolver();

    });
    </script>

</head>
```

Comment: First of all jQuery should be defined *before* any other library that uses it. And we can't see what is going on with your image slider without the rest of your markup.

Comment: are you getting any errors in the console? and yes, jQuery should defenitely be defined before any other libraries that depend on it.

Comment: No errors. Seems like both are clashing somehow. is there a way I can tell them to run both?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put jQuery before other scripts.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

P.S. Is the jquery version too old?

Comment: I imagine it would be since the latest is 1.11.0.

Answer (score 0):

This needs to go before the other libraries:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You also need to look up what version of jQuery they're using because 1.3.1 is a ridiculously old version. That might be a problem in its own right because a lot changed in 1.5 and in one of the versions that followed (can't remember which) regarding ajax and eventing.

Comment: Im 100% positive its an old version. Moving the script you suggested to the top didn't do anything besides flipping my problem. Slider works and testimonials don't. :(